# vim cursorline not working properly

Tags: vim

I have the following in my .vimrc:

```
hi CursorLine ctermfg=00 ctermbg=00 cterm=bold
```

I *should* be unable to read the line the cursor is on, but I am able, because the text appears in grey. If I remove `cterm=bold`, I get true black, so it seems to be black or bold, but not both. Is "bold" a variable for a color in the theme (solarized light)? Or is my terminal theme overriding the fg color somehow? I get the exact same results in various terminal apps (on Xubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By typing `:help attr-list`  you will get a whole list of possible values for `cterm` argument:

> ```
>                                         bold underline undercurl
>                                         inverse italic standout
> term={attr-list}                        attr-list highlight-term E418 
>         attr-list is a comma separated list (without spaces) of the
>         following items (in any order):
>                 bold 
>                 underline
>                 undercurl       not always available
>                 reverse
>                 inverse         same as reverse
>                 italic
>                 standout
>                 NONE            no attributes used (used to reset it)
> ```

These terms are not colors but they are considered as **typographical emphasis**. They **add more** font and shape to the text.

Comment: But it does override the color, as well. As noted above, it seems to depend on the terminal settings.

Answer (score 1):

First, highlighting of the cursorline is disabled by default so there's no reason whatsoever to hack your colorscheme if you don't want it: just don't enable it. For the record, that feature is enabled with `:set cursorline` and disabled with `:set nocursorline`.

See `:help 'cusorline'`.

Second, the "bold" keyword is passed more or less directly to your terminal emulator which is ultimately in charge of deciding what to do with it. It may display "bold" text with a bolded font or use a brighter or color or… whatever. Use "bold" *only* if you know how your terminal emulator will react to it.

Third, Solarized is an over-engineered and very poorly written colorscheme that's a lot harder to hack than necessary. It's really a bad platform for experiments and customization.

Comment: I tried to confirm what you say about cursorline, but when I commented it out in my .vimrc, there was still highlighting, so I assume it's baked into solarized. 

If I understand you correctly, I need to choose a colorscheme for my terminal first, and then get vim set up after that. The whole "bold" thing is really annoying, because for a long time, I had it working, and I liked it. 

I like the colors in solarized, but I agree about it being over-engineered.